# Ayuda para enviar AJAX con NippleJS

Tags: javascript, html, python, ajax

Estoy usando nippleJS: https://github.com/yoannmoinet/nipplejs

No estoy seguro al 100% si es posible enviar la información del joystick pero diría que sí.
Quiero enviar un formulario AJAX con la posición del joystick y quiero que sea en tiempo real para controlar unos motores. No consigo enviar la información. Estoy usando esto:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#static').onclick(function(evento){
        /* Cancelamos el envío del formulario */
        evento.stopPropagation();
        evento.preventDefault();

        var dataString = $('#static').serialize()

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cgi-bin/motorcontrol.py",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>


<div id="static"></div>
<script src="./dist/nipplejs.min.js"></script>   
<script>
   var static = nipplejs.create({
       zone: document.getElementById('static'),
       mode: 'static',
       position: {left: '75%', top: '50%'},
       color: 'black'
   });
</script>
```

Estoy usando .onclick para que solo funcione cuando estoy pulsando el joystick. El script al que va dirigido es este:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb
import socket
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
searchterm = form.getvalue('static')

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sent = socket.sendto(str(searchterm) + "3", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
```

Y este:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import serial, socket

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 31113))
print "Esperando conexion"

while True:
  # Recibimos hasta 200 caracteres en un paquete UDP
  datos, remoto = socket.recvfrom(200)
  print("Datos recibidos de " + str(remoto) + " - " + str(datos))
  ser.write(str(datos))
  # Devolvemos los datos recibidos a modo de "ACK" (opcional)
  sent = socket.sendto(datos, remoto)
```

Los uso para ver los datos que llegan pero no llega nada de nada.

Comment: donde te da el error no se envia via ajax? no se conecta al socket?}

Comment: Diria que el ajax no funciona, directamente no envía nada al script así que por eso no funciona. He estado mirando y la posición del joystick si que se puede saber: http://yoannmoinet.github.io/nipplejs/#demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación oficial está documentada la interfaz de eventos que ofrece, siendo el [evento `move`](https://github.com/yoannmoinet/nipplejs#move) al que parece que necesitas suscribir tu código para mandar actualizaciones del movimiento y el [evento `end`](https://github.com/yoannmoinet/nipplejs#end) para enviar un retorno al punto neutro:

```
<script>
    /*  false: no se está enviando nada al servidor
        true: se están enviando datos al servidor
        datos: hay datos pendientes de ser enviados al servidor
    */
    var pendiente = false;
    var joystick = nipplejs.create({
        zone: document.getElementById('static'),
        mode: 'static',
        position: {
            left: '75%',
            top: '50%',
        },
        color: 'black',
    });
    function controlador(evento, datos) {
        /* Comprobamos si podemos hacer el envío o encolarlo */
        if (pendiente === false) {
            /* Marcamos que tenemos un envío pendiente de ser completado */
            pendiente = true;
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "URL_A_TU_SCRIPT",
                data: {
                    grados: datos.angle.degree,
                    distancia: datos.distance,
                },
                dataType: "json", /* OJO: Esto es lo que se espera recibir en lo siguiente */
                success: function (datos) {
                    console.log(datos);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    console.log("Fin trabajo");
                    /* Si hay un dato en cola de envío lo enviamos */
                    if (pendiente === true) {
                        /* Marcamos el trabajo como finalizado */
                        pendiente = false;
                    } else {
                        var datos = pendiente;
                        pendiente = false;
                        controlador(evento, datos);
                    }
                },
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Trabajo encolado");
            /* Ponemos en cola de envío el dato actual */
            pendiente = datos;
        }
    }
    /* Configuramos el controlador del evento "move" del joystick */
    joystick.on('move', controlador);
    /* Cuando finalizamos el uso del joystick inyectamos una posición neutra */
    joystick.on('end', function (evento, datos) {
        /* Simulamos un evento en posición neutra */
        controlador(evento, {
            angle: { degree: 0.0 },
            distance: 0,
        });
    });
</script>
```

He implementado un gestor de colas de envío para no saturar al servidor con peticiones XHR si hay eventos muy rápidos que no puedan ser atendidos por el servidor web. Hasta que no se recibe respuesta a la petición anterior no se envía la siguiente, y si había una petición pendiente de ser enviada se sustituye por la última recibida.

Tu script python debe modificarse para recibir correctamente los valores del XHR:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb
import socket
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
grados = form.getvalue('grados')
distancia = form.getvalue('distancia')

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Esto debes modificarlo para enviar lo necesario al arduino/servidor UDP
#sent = socket.sendto(str(searchterm) + "3", ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
sent = socket.sendto("G:" + grados + ";D:" + distancia, ('127.0.0.1', 31113))
```